Executing DB2 SQL stored procedure via JCL
I am trying to execute SQL db2 stored procedure using DSNTEP2 via JCL.
// SET DATE=241122                                                      
/*                                                                      
//***********************************************************  
//*   CREATE STORED PROCEDURE DCSTEP2F IS USING DSNTEP2                 
//***********************************************************  
//CATDEL2  EXEC  CATDEL,                          
//  INNAME=WW.W.DCD.D&DATE..BUILDSPR.KLI30105.TR  
//BUILD01  EXEC  DCSTEP2F,                        
//  DB2SYS=DBB0,                                  
//  SQLLIB=TEST.RIZ.SP,                           
//  SQLNAME=BUILD@SP,                             
//  OUTDSN=WW.W.DCD.D&DATE..BUILDSPR.KLI30105.TR  
//*********************************************************** 
//*   EXECUTE STORED PROCEDURE DCSTEP2F IS USING DSNTEP2                
//***********************************************************//CATDEL2  EXEC  CATDEL,                                                
//  INNAME=WW.W.DCD.D&DATE..CALL.KLI30105.TR                            
//EXECU01  EXEC  DCSTEP2F,                                              
//  DB2SYS=DBB0,                                                        
//  SQLLIB=TEST.RIZ.SP,                                                 
//  SQLNAME=CALL@SP,                                                    
//  OUTDSN=WW.W.DCD.D&DATE..CALL.KLI30105.TR        

The JCL step to create the simple stored procedure is successful as shown in below code
***INPUT STATEMENT:                                                    
  SET CURRENT SQLID = 'SIWRO1'~                                         
  RESULT OF SQL STATEMENT:                                              
  DSNT400I SQLCODE = 000,  SUCCESSFUL EXECUTION                         
  DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 00000 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE                      
  DSNT416I SQLERRD    = 0  0  0  -1  0  0 SQL DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION    
  DSNT416I SQLERRD    = X'00000000'  X'00000000'  X'00000000'  X'FFFFFFF
           INFORMATION                                                  
 SET       SUCCESSFUL                                                   
1PAGE    1                                                              
 ***INPUT STATEMENT:                                                    
  CREATE PROCEDURE DWR000A.HELLO_WORLD1(                                
   OUT MSG_OUT   VARCHAR(35)                                            
  )                                                                     
  LANGUAGE SQL                                                          
  READS SQL DATA                                                        
  BEGIN                                                                 
    SET MSG_OUT = 'HELLO WORLD';                                        
  END                                                                   
  ~                                                                    
 RESULT OF SQL STATEMENT:                                              
 DSNT400I SQLCODE = 000,  SUCCESSFUL EXECUTION                         
 DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 00000 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE                      
 DSNT416I SQLERRD    = 0  0  0  -1  0  0 SQL DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION    
 DSNT416I SQLERRD    = X'00000000'  X'00000000'  X'00000000'  X'FFFFFFF
          INFORMATION                                                  
CREATE    SUCCESSFUL            

However, I am having issue with the executing the stored procedure step. result below
**INPUT STATEMENT:                                                      
EXEC SQL                                                                
     HELLO_WORLD1()                                                     
END-EXEC                                                                
 ;                                                                      
QLERROR ON   EXEC      COMMAND, PREPARE   FUNCTION                      
RESULT OF SQL STATEMENT:                                                
DSNT408I SQLCODE = -104, ERROR:  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "HELLO_WORLD1". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: <ERR_STMT> <WNG_STMT>
         TRANSFER GET SQL SAVEPOINT HOLD FREE                           
DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 42601 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE                        
DSNT415I SQLERRP    = DSNHPARS SQL PROCEDURE DETECTING ERROR            
DSNT416I SQLERRD    = 3  0  0  -1  10  502 SQL DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION   
DSNT416I SQLERRD    = X'00000003'  X'00000000'  X'00000000'  X'FFFFFFFF'
         INFORMATION                                             

   

I am not sure what the issue is since the procedure is there in SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES where I ran SPUFI in the DB2.
I am really new at this stored procedure. Appreciate any assistance. Thank you in advance.
updated after comments.
11/26/2024
I rerun again to execute the stored procedure but get this error
***INPUT STATEMENT:                                                             
 EXEC SQL                                                                       
      CALL HELLO_WORLD1()                                                       
 END-EXEC                                                                       
  ;                                                                             
SQLERROR ON   EXEC      COMMAND, PREPARE   FUNCTION                             
 RESULT OF SQL STATEMENT:                                                       
 DSNT408I SQLCODE = -84, ERROR:  UNACCEPTABLE SQL STATEMENT                     
 DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 42612 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE                               
 DSNT415I SQLERRP    = DSNHAPL2 SQL PROCEDURE DETECTING ERROR                   
 DSNT416I SQLERRD    = 1  0  0  -1  10  101 SQL DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION          
 DSNT416I SQLERRD    = X'00000001'  X'00000000'  X'00000000'  X'FFFFFFFF'  X'000
      INFORMATION               

My stored procedure is a simple hello world as below. My company is using stored procedure for first time and we trying to learn.  We using standard IBM DB2
CREATE PROCEDURE DWR000A.HELLO_WORLD1(
 OUT MSG_OUT   VARCHAR(35)            
)                                     
LANGUAGE SQL                          
READS SQL DATA                        
BEGIN                                 
  SET MSG_OUT = 'HELLO WORLD';        
END                                   
 ~                                                      
COMMIT;                                
         

Appreciate any feedback and advice

i updated my post with suggestion. Appreciate your time and expertise. Kindly assist

It seems that you have to invoke the stored-procedure via a host-program (i.e. indirectly) and change the JCL to invoke that host-program. Write your host-program in COBOL or other supported language, and in that program you place the EXEC SQL  CALL stored-procedure END EXEC.

Question can a native db2 store procedure be call directly via JCL without having to code a host program. If yes, I will code another store procedure to run simple select query
